# How to define the subset with the two smallest elements

Tags: notation

I am having a bit of trouble with basic notation.

I have a set of color value pairs e.g. `CV = {(blue, 3), (orange,54), (red, 1), (brown, 43), (yellow,7)}` and I want to define the subset that contains the lowest two values. In our case that would be `Subset = {(blue, 3), (red, 1)}`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the context ? Programming or maths. Why do yo want a specific notation ?

Comment: Why do you insist on having notation for this?  Words convey the meaning in a rather clear, concise, and relatively unambiguous way.  If you try to use notation for it instead, you run the risk of it being more confusing and difficult to read.

Comment: @YvesDaoust math.I have run into the problem that it is often not exactly clear to others what I mean. So I was wondering if there is a clean notation for this one.

Comment: What is the context ? Programming or maths ?

Comment: Note that for this subset to be unambiguously defined, there must be at least two pairs, and the values must be distinct.

Answer (score 0):

$S \in \mathcal P(A) \land |S| = 2 \land (\exists (a,b) \in S \implies (b = \min{S[\mathrm{Dom}\, f]} \lor b = \min{(S[\mathrm{Dom} \, f] / \min{S[\mathrm{Dom} \,f]})})$.

Whew. I wonder why you need this, tho.
Note that this set must exist by the axiom of specification.